# Getting Multiple Screens Aligned in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, alignment

I'm trying to get my two screens aligned so the mouse cursor doesn't jump when I cross from one screen to another.  I understand that I can go into ***Screen Resolution*** in order to drag the screens relative to each other.

I am using a 1920x1080 (landscape) screen with a 1080x1920 (portrait) screen.  According to my calculations:

```
(First screen height - Second screen height) / 2
(1920 - 1080) / 2 = 420
```

This means that I need to set the second screen to the coordinates `(1920, -420)`.  However when I try to drag the screen to those coordinates, it snaps to either `(1920, -411)` or `(1920, -426)`.  My mouse still jumps by a few pixels.

**Is there a way to specify the coordinates to `(1920, -420)` manually?**

Comment: It may be simpler to swap one of your screens to get a pair with the same resolution.  Someone at work or school may be willing to swap, or your may be able to buy one.  eBay, Craiglist, used PC market, neighbors, etc.  If you don't get a precise model match, the colors, viewing angle, brightness, etc, may vary.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage The screens are the same resolution.  I'm trying to use one of them in portrait mode.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Besides, I am in a business/enterprise environment and Craigslist and the like are not really an option.